# Reading Image from memory, knowing pointer to memory. VC++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I've a camera that comes with an c++ api and SDK.
There is an callback Function that returns a
C++ pointer to the starting point of some RAW Image data stored in Memory
I want to 
1) Get the Image
2) convert it to some image format
3) save it to hard disk

pointer is char*

How can I do it in VC++.
Thanks.

EDIT:
reposted question here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10826313/reading-image-from-memory-and-painting-it-in-a-vc-mfc-application

Comment: You do not mention the SDK, or what you have tried so there is nothing we can really recommend to you other than reading up on what a [Raw Image](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raw_image_format) is and using a [library](http://www.libraw.org/) to process it.

Comment: Ok, reposting question with details...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Investigate [OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/) to convert the image to some format and then save it on the disk.

You might want to [take a look at this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6924790/opencv-create-mat-from-camera-data) as well.